# /dev/mapper/rhel-root is at 100%

Tags: linux, command-line, rhel, mount, root

Good day,
Please I am having my /dev/mapper/rhel-root full is there a way to reduce it, I've tried to clear yum by doing **yum clean all**
Kindly help out
Thanks

[image]

I used this command the command du -sh and I checked the /var/lib The size of the files there is 14gb and I checked /var/log too, the size of the file there is 205mb Is there anything I could remove that could free up the space

the out of vgs is
rhel 1 3 0 wz--n- <278.17g 0

Comment: Firstly, do not post pictures. Copy what you have from terminal and paste it into the question using the code blocks. As far as the question, you're going to have to use `du -sh` on the directories in `/` to find out which ones are using the most space. Some to start with are `/root` and `/var/` and its subdirectories such as `/var/lib`, `/var/log`, /var/tmp`. It's also useful to check `/opt`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the result of `vgs`?

Comment: @Nasir Riley
Thank you, I used this command the command  du -sh   and  I checked the /var/lib 
The size of the files there is 14gb and I checked /var/log too, the size of the file there is 205mb 
Is there anything I could remove that could free up the space

Comment: @Romeo Ninov 

the out of vgs is 
rhel   1   3   0 wz--n- <278.17g    0

Comment: @DadaJoseph, add this to question, not in comment. And clean `/var` and `/root`